# ProgressBar with BackgroundWorker MVVM

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, progress-bar

I just recently started getting acquainted with progress bar. I have an MVVM project How can I use `ICommand` in `DoWork`?
I have many functions for exporting, adding, downloading, etc (considering that all calculations will be inside these functions).

Can I use them like this in `DoWork`?

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker worker;
private int progress;
public int CurrentProgress
{
    get { return this.progress; }
    set
    {
        if (this.progress != value)
        {
            this.progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentProgress");
        }
    }
}

private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CurrentProgress = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   ICommand ExportXml;
   ICommand DownloadFile;
   ICommand AddFile;
}

public ICommand ExportXml
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveXml = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                Filter = ".xml file|*.xml",
                DefaultExt = ".xml"
            };
            if (saveXml.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
               ExportXml(saveXml.Filename);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export anonymous metod to named method and then can use this method in code.

```
public ICommand ExportXmlCommand => new Command(ExportXml);

private void ExportXml()
{
    SaveFileDialog saveXml = new SaveFileDialog()
    {
        Filter = ".xml file|*.xml",
        DefaultExt = ".xml"
    };
    if (saveXml.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        ExportXml(saveXml.Filename);
    }
}
```